# VBA - Problema da mochila

Tags: vba, microsoft-excel

No excel eu tenho a seguinte tabela

```
| Produtos  | Preço |
| Produto A | 100   |
| Produto B | 250   |
| Produto C | 200   |
| Produto D | 800   |
| Produto E | 560   |
| Produto F | 970   |
...
```

E eu gostaria de fazer todas as combinações possíveis através do preço

```
Exemplo preço: 1000
```

Resultado

```
Produto A x10
Produto B x4
Produto A x5 Produto B x2
Produto D x1 Produto C x1
...
```

O número total de combinações devem ser iguais para o preço informado, e poderá ter diversas combinações diferentes de N produtos para N produtos.
A minha maior duvida é como criar um algorítimo desta forma?
Tentei executar um for de todos os produtos, mas acredito que esta não seja a melhor maneira

```vba
For i = 1 To linha 'total de produtos'
    linhaId = CInt(Plan1.Cells(i + 1, 4)) 

    If (linhaId > 0) Then
        preco = CInt(Plan1.Cells(linhaId, 2))
        If ((soma + preco) <= CInt(limiteTotalPreco)) Then
            soma = soma + preco
        Else
            Plan2.Cells(newlinha, 1) = soma
            newlinha = newlinha + 1

            soma = preco
        End If
    End If
Next
```

O problema é que a combinação não é feita, e não tenho consigo achar uma solução para executar este loop de informações

Comment: O que quer dizer quando diz "E eu gostaria de fazer todas as combinações possíveis através do preço"? Não estou conseguindo entender o que pretende fazer

Comment: Agora entendi ... você quer citar um preço, e ver quais são as combinações de cada produto (e até vários produtos diferentes) que igual aquele preço... certo?

Comment: Onde você está guardando as combinações?

Comment: @MattJohnson Isto mesmo, e também pode ser o mesmo produto 2x ou 3x combinado com outros produtos

Comment: Você primeiro precisa encontrar o algoritmo que faça o que você precisa, mesmo que seja pseudo-algoritmo. Depois fazer a pergunta.

Comment: O problema da mochila original envolve encontrar uma solução ótima (http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Problema_da_mochila: "*Metaforicamente podemos entendê-lo como o desafio de encher uma mochila sem ultrapassar um determinado limite de peso, **otimizando o valor do produto carregado**.*"). No entanto, você deseja produzir todas as combinações possíveis. Note que se você testar apenas as combinações entre produtos distintos (ignorando combinações *adicionais* do mesmo produto 2x, 3x, ..., etc), o problema já teria complexidade exponencial. Você tem alguma intenção específica com esse algoritmo?

Comment: @LuizVieira eu pensei no "problema da mochila", porque eu achei que poderia ser a solução para construir o meu algoritmo, pela questão "encher a mochila sem ultrapassar um determinando limite de peso", no meu caso eu quero encher um carrinho com N produtos e combinações definida pelo o limite do Valor

Comment: @Makah inicialmente o algoritmo que eu encontrei é este "problema da mochila" o grande problema que já não tenho tanta certeza se ele será totalmente útil...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Como eu mencionei no comentário, o seu problema não é exatamente o [problema da mochila](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Problema_da_mochila) clássico, porque você não está buscando encontrar uma solução ótima (como o número mínimo de carrinhos de compra para acomodar todos os produtos, por exemplo). Ainda assim você tem razão no fato de que o seu problema lembra os problemas de otimização combinatória.

Eu fiz uma tentativa bastante "inocente" (no sentido de que não me preocupei com o desempenho do algoritmo) com a esperança de que possa lhe ajudar. Valeu como um exercício bacana pra eu lembrar como funciona o VBA. :)

O princípio da solução que eu estou propondo é o seguinte:

- Assim como na abordagem gulosa de resolução do problema da mochila clássico, os itens são ordenados em ordem decrescente de preço. Isso ajuda no sentido de que os itens mais caros são eliminados rapidamente (no seu exemplo dá pra notar que o produto F, que custa 950) não "cabe" no carrinho de máximo 1000 com nenhum outro produto).
- Como você gostaria de ter as diversas combinações de cada produto (x1, x2, x3, ..., etc), é necessário calcular qual é o máximo de itens de um produto que caberia no carrinho. Você notará no algoritmo que existe um laço (`For iQtd = 1 To iQtdMax`) justamente pra tratar essas combinações.
- A implementação é inerentemente recursiva (e aqui está a minha preocupação com relação a complexidade - mais a respeito no final), de forma que para cada quantidade de um produto o algoritmo busca todas as possíveis combinações dos produtos seguintes que cabem no *preço restante* (lembrando que o algoritmo se baseia no fato de que a lista de produtos está ordenada do maior para o menor preço). Por exemplo, quando o algoritmo estiver tratando o produto B (que pode ser colocado no carrinho no máximo `1000 / 250 = 4` vezes), ele irá fazer as combinações para as quantidades de B de 1 a 4. Supondo que se está no laço em que a quantidade iQtd é igual a 3. Isso significa que no carrinho haverá o equivalente a `3 x 250 = 750`, e por isso restará apenas 150 para tentar incluir os próximos itens de valor menor (isto é, os produtos C e A). Note que o valor dessa diferença é passado na chamada recursiva da função `Combine`.
- A função `Combine` trata os elementos utilizando diretamente o objeto `Worksheet.Range` do VBA, mas você pode trocar isso para uma matriz se preferir. Além disso, o seu retorno é uma matriz de strings com as combinações da mesma forma que você usou na sua questão, meramente como forma de ilustração. Você pode modificar pra devolver da maneira que achar mais apropriado.

Eis aqui o código que eu construi de exemplo.

```vb
Option Base 1

' Macro chamada pelo botão na planilha "Dados".
' Apenas faz a mágica e cria uma nova planilha "Resultado" com as combinações.
Sub GenerateList()

On Error Resume Next

    Dim dMaxPrice As Double
    Dim oData As Range
    Dim aResp() As String
    Dim oSheet As Worksheet

    ' Ordena os dados em ordem descendente de preço
    Set oData = Range("A2:B7")
    oData.Sort key1:=Range("B2:B7"), Order1:=xlDescending

    ' Obtém o preço máximo
    dMaxPrice = CDbl(Cells(1, 5).Value)

    ' Monta a lista de combinações com os dados
    aResp = Combine(oData, dMaxPrice)

    Set oSheet = Worksheets("Resultado")
    If Err = 0 Then
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        oSheet.Delete
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End If

    Set oSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets("Dados"))
    oSheet.Name = "Resultado"
    For i = 1 To UBound(aResp)
        oSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value = aResp(i)
    Next i
    oSheet.Columns(1).AutoFit
    oSheet.Activate

End Sub

' Esta é a função que propriamente faz as combinações
' Ela está meramente recursiva, então note que sua complexidade é exponencial com relação
' à quantidade de dados de entrada.
'
' Parâmetros:
' oData Objeto Worksheet.Range com os dados processados em cada chamada recursiva.
' dMaxPrice Valor (double) com o limite de preço restante no nível da chamada.
'
' Retorno:
' Retorna um array de strings com as combinações no formato "Produto A x? Produto B x? ..."
' como no exemplo da sua questão.
Function Combine(ByVal oData As Range, ByVal dMaxPrice) As Variant

On Error Resume Next

    Dim sProduct As String
    Dim dPrice As Double
    Dim iQtdMax As Integer
    Dim sRangeDef As String
    Dim oSubData As Range
    Dim aRet() As String
    Dim aCombReports() As String
    Dim iSize As Integer

    For iProd = 1 To oData.Rows.Count

        ' Nome e preço do produto atual
        sProduct = oData.Cells(iProd, 1)
        dPrice = oData.Cells(iProd, 2)

        ' Quantidade máxima de itens do produto atual, segundo seu preço e o limite máximo
        iQtdMax = Int(dMaxPrice / dPrice)

        ' Demais produtos no intervalo de dados além do produto atual
        If (iProd + 1 <= oData.Rows.Count) Then
            sRangeDef = "A" + CStr(iProd + 1) + ":B" + CStr(oData.Rows.Count)
            Set oSubData = oData.Range(sRangeDef)
        Else
            Set oSubData = Nothing
        End If

        ' Calcula todas as combinações de quantidades do produto atual,
        ' recursivamente incluindo as combinações dos demais produtos DE
        ' MENOR VALOR (devido ao fato do intervalo original de dados estar
        ' ordenado por preço em ordem descrescente)
        For iQtd = 1 To iQtdMax

            sReport = sProduct + " x" + CStr(iQtd) + " "
            dPriceRest = dMaxPrice - (iQtd * dPrice)

            ' Chamada recursiva indicando o preço máximo descontado o total de itens do produto inicial incluídos
            ' (Se, é claro, há preço sobrando para incluir mais produtos).
            If dPriceRest > 0 And Not oSubData Is Nothing Then
                aCombReports = Combine(oSubData, dPriceRest)
            Else
                Erase aCombReports
            End If

            ' Monta o retorno com as combinações obtidas para os demais produtos
            Err = 0
            iCombs = UBound(aCombReports)
            If Err = 0 Then
                Err = 0
                For Each sCombRep In aCombReports
                    Err = 0 ' <-------- LINHA ADICIONADA NA EDIÇÃO
                    iSize = UBound(aRet)
                    If Err <> 0 Then iSize = 0
                    ReDim Preserve aRet(iSize + 1)
                    aRet(iSize + 1) = sReport + sCombRep
                Next

            ' Se não retornou combinações, monta o retorno apenas com o produto atual
            Else
                Err = 0
                iSize = UBound(aRet)
                If Err <> 0 Then iSize = 0
                ReDim Preserve aRet(iSize + 1)
                aRet(iSize + 1) = sReport
            End If

        Next iQtd

    Next iProd

    ' Devolve o array de combinações
    Combine = aRet

End Function
```

**Observações importantes:**

1. Como eu disse, não se trata exatamente do problema da mochila, embora seja um problema de combinatória.
2. A implementação que eu estou sugerindo é *bem inocente* e não tem qualquer preocupação com desempenho. Note que o algoritmo é recursivo e por isso sua complexidade é exponencial em relação ao tamanho dos dados de entrada. No seu exemplo funcionou muito bem, mas para um volume de dados (quantidade de produtos) grande pode ficar inviável.
3. Talvez seja possível utilizar [programação dinâmica](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o_din%C3%A2mica) para diminuir o custo da recursão. Mas, honestamente, não cheguei a pensar a respeito e deixo essa lição de casa pra você (ou pra resposta de outra pessoa).

O resultado que esse código produz é esse (total de 72 combinações):

```
Produto F x1 
Produto D x1 Produto C x1 
Produto D x1 Produto A x1 
Produto D x1 Produto A x2 
Produto E x1 Produto B x1 Produto A x1 
Produto E x1 Produto C x1 Produto A x1 
Produto E x1 Produto C x1 Produto A x2 
Produto E x1 Produto C x2 
Produto E x1 Produto A x1 
Produto E x1 Produto A x2 
Produto E x1 Produto A x3 
Produto E x1 Produto A x4 
Produto B x1 Produto C x1 Produto A x1 
Produto B x1 Produto C x1 Produto A x2 
Produto B x1 Produto C x1 Produto A x3 
Produto B x1 Produto C x1 Produto A x4 
Produto B x1 Produto C x1 Produto A x5 
Produto B x1 Produto C x2 Produto A x1 
Produto B x1 Produto C x2 Produto A x2 
Produto B x1 Produto C x2 Produto A x3 
Produto B x1 Produto C x3 Produto A x1 
Produto B x1 Produto A x1 
Produto B x1 Produto A x2 
Produto B x1 Produto A x3 
Produto B x1 Produto A x4 
Produto B x1 Produto A x5 
Produto B x1 Produto A x6 
Produto B x1 Produto A x7 
Produto B x2 Produto C x1 Produto A x1 
Produto B x2 Produto C x1 Produto A x2 
Produto B x2 Produto C x1 Produto A x3 
Produto B x2 Produto C x2 Produto A x1 
Produto B x2 Produto A x1 
Produto B x2 Produto A x2 
Produto B x2 Produto A x3 
Produto B x2 Produto A x4 
Produto B x2 Produto A x5 
Produto B x3 Produto C x1 
Produto B x3 Produto A x1 
Produto B x3 Produto A x2 
Produto B x4 
Produto C x1 Produto A x1 
Produto C x1 Produto A x2 
Produto C x1 Produto A x3 
Produto C x1 Produto A x4 
Produto C x1 Produto A x5 
Produto C x1 Produto A x6 
Produto C x1 Produto A x7 
Produto C x1 Produto A x8 
Produto C x2 Produto A x1 
Produto C x2 Produto A x2 
Produto C x2 Produto A x3 
Produto C x2 Produto A x4 
Produto C x2 Produto A x5 
Produto C x2 Produto A x6 
Produto C x3 Produto A x1 
Produto C x3 Produto A x2 
Produto C x3 Produto A x3 
Produto C x3 Produto A x4 
Produto C x4 Produto A x1 
Produto C x4 Produto A x2 
Produto C x5 
Produto A x1 
Produto A x2 
Produto A x3 
Produto A x4 
Produto A x5 
Produto A x6 
Produto A x7 
Produto A x8 
Produto A x9 
Produto A x10
```

Comment: Sinceramente Luiz muito show a sua resposta cara, vou analisar aqui todos os itens, muito obrigado!

Comment: Luiz funcionou perfeitamente, porém só tem uma parte do código que eu não entendi muito bem, se eu coloco o valor Preço máximo: 1800, traz o resultado "Produto F x1 Produto A x8" e esta é a unica combinação do "Produto F", sendo que poderia ter também "Produto F x1 Produto C x4". Isto só acontece com o produto de maior valor, isto acontece devido ao fato que você mencionou acima "A implementação é inerentemente recursiva..."

Comment: @Tiago De fato havia um erro, mas não tem nada a ver com a recursão. Esqueci de reinicializar a variável de erro utilizada para checar se a matriz de retorno estava vazia. Corrigi e marquei com um comentário no código.

Comment: Boa tarde. Seria possível uparem novamente esta planilha. Tenho exatamente a mesma necessidade exposta aqui.

Comment: Olá @AndersonGomes. Não sei o porquê, mas a planilha foi deletada na minha conta do 4Shared. Já verifiquei no Recicle Bin dele e não está lá. Eu também não a mantive em meu computador porque é um exemplo muito simples. Então, infelizmente não a tenho mais. Mas é simples mesmo, ela só tinha os dados dos produtos (de A a F) tal como o AP coloca na pergunta, e um botão que executava a macro com o código (que você pode copiar da resposta)