# Programação VBA - Recursividade, mochila booleana

Tags: vba, excel-vba, recursão

Tenho uma situação semelhante a mochila booleana.
Possuo uma tabela com N linhas. A coluna 'A' contem uma metragem (m²), a coluna 'B' contem um preço (R$).

Preciso obter todas as somas possíveis da coluna 'A' ate um determinado valor em metros (x) e, deve ser mostrado a melhor combinação de soma de metros e valor de modo que, em metros, não ultrapasse o valor 'x' que for estipulado.

Em pesquisas, consegui um código que, a principio resolveria o problema mas tenho obtido erros diversos, como por exemplo, a variável 'Me' (nunca ouvi falar).

Segue o código.
Gostaria da ajuda para resolver a questão.

```html
Option Explicit
'retirado comando private
Sub cmbBerechnen_Click()
   Dim dblZielwert   As Double
   Dim dblToleranz   As Double
   Dim adblBeträge() As Double
   Dim varResult     As Variant
   Dim m             As Long
   Dim n             As Long
   Dim gblnStop      As Boolean
   
   gblnStop = False
   
   With Me
      dblZielwert = .Range("B2")
      dblToleranz = .Range("C2")
      .Range("D2:IV65536").ClearContents
      ReDim adblBeträge(1 To 100)
      For m = 2 To 101
         If (.Cells(m, 1) <> "") And (IsNumeric(.Cells(m, 1))) Then
            adblBeträge(m - 1) = .Cells(m, 1)
         Else
            ReDim Preserve adblBeträge(1 To m - 1)
            Exit For
         End If
      Next
      ReDim Preserve adblBeträge(1 To UBound(adblBeträge) - 1)
      
      MsgBox "Found Solutions : " & Kombinations(adblBeträge, dblZielwert, Me, 4, 2, dblToleranz)
      
      Application.StatusBar = False
   End With
Call CompileOutput
End Sub
Private Sub cmdAbbrechen_Click()
   gblnStop = True
End Sub
Option Explicit
' Set to "True" for Stop
Public gblnStop As Boolean
Public Function Kombinations(SourceNumbers As Variant, Target As Double, DestSheet As Worksheet, _
   DestCol As Long, DestRow As Long, Optional Tolerance As Double, Optional Previously As Variant, _
   Optional ActLevel As Long, Optional ActFound As Long) As Long
   
   Dim i As Long
   Dim k As Long
   Dim dblCompare As Double
   Dim dblDummy As Double
   Dim varDummy As Variant
   
   ' Do Other events (prevents for freeze)
   DoEvents
   
   ' Global Variable to Stop when is set True
   If gblnStop = True Then Exit Function
   If Not IsMissing(Previously) Then
      
      ' Calculate Sum
      For Each varDummy In Previously
         dblCompare = dblCompare + varDummy
      Next
      
   Else
      ' First time call
   
      ' Sort source by size
      For i = 1 To UBound(SourceNumbers)
          For k = i + 1 To UBound(SourceNumbers)
              If SourceNumbers(k) < SourceNumbers(i) Then
                  dblDummy = SourceNumbers(i)
                  SourceNumbers(i) = SourceNumbers(k)
                  SourceNumbers(k) = dblDummy
              End If
          Next
      Next
      
      ' Make new collection
      Set Previously = New Collection
      
   End If
   If ActLevel = 0 Then ActLevel = LBound(SourceNumbers)
   For i = ActLevel To UBound(SourceNumbers) ' Test all Numbers
   
      ' Add act Value to Collection
      Previously.Add SourceNumbers(i)
      
      ' Calculate act sum
      dblCompare = dblCompare + SourceNumbers(i)
      
      If Abs(Target - dblCompare) < (0.01 + Tolerance) Then 'trying to set the limit
         
         ' Act sum is in target range
         
         k = DestCol - 1 ' Calculate Destination Column
         
         ActFound = ActFound + 1 ' Count Solutions
         
         With DestSheet
         
            ' Save Solution Array in Worksheet
            For Each varDummy In Previously
            
               k = k + 1
               .Cells(DestRow - 1 + ActFound, k) = varDummy
               
            Next
            
         End With
         
         ' Delete following line, or set finally
         ' Statusbar to "False"
         Application.StatusBar = "Solutions Count : " & ActFound
         
         ' Remove act Value from Collection
         Previously.Remove Previously.Count
      
      ElseIf dblCompare < (Target + 0.01 + Tolerance) Then
      
         ' Act sum is lower then target range
         
         ' Recursive call  the same Function with
         ' higher Level
         Kombinations SourceNumbers, Target, DestSheet, DestCol, DestRow, _
            Tolerance, Previously, i + 1, ActFound
            
         ' Remove act Value from Collection
         Previously.Remove Previously.Count
         
         ' Remove act Value from Sum
         dblCompare = dblCompare - SourceNumbers(i)
      
      Else
   
         ' Act sum is greater then target range
         ' No other Solutions possible in this level
         Previously.Remove Previously.Count
         Exit For
      End If
   Next ' Test with higher Number
   Kombinations = ActFound
End Function
```

Alguma ideia de como fazer o código rodar?

Comment: o me é como se fosse um "this" no vb, que nesse caso representaria a excel sheet correspondente

Comment: `Me` se refere à instância da Classe sendo utilizada.[Ler a referência oficial](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/me-keyword). Muito utilizado em formulários.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [VBA - Problema da mochila](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4406/vba-problema-da-mochila)

Comment: Creio que você possui um problema de otimização. Você pode resolver isto com Pesquisa Operacional (PO), Programação Linear (PL), Solver. Estes são alguns nomes para o tipo de modelagem para resolver o problema. Acho que você não vai precisar saber todas as combinações, somente a com melhor custo/benefício, isso pode ser obtido com a otimização do problema.

Comment: @LucasMiranda Obrigada pela dica!

Comment: @danieltakeshi Agradeço a indicação do post do Guilherme mas temos uma diferença nos conceitos da problemática. O caso que apresento procura, realmente, a solução ótima de soma.
Quanto ao solver, como expliquei anteriormente, ele exige o valor exato da soma. Como este caso permite a soma aproximada do valor 'x', torna improdutivo ficar fazendo testes com os valores para que o solver encontre as somas.

Comment: Na verdade, você vai utilizar no solver uma função objetivo (OF) de minimização do custo. E nas restrições do modelo (s.t.) criar a restrição para procurar o valor mais aproximado da medida desejada em m². Como não é exato, a programação pode se tornar não linear. Não é uma modelagem simples, mas também não é de outro mundo. Talvez algum especialista da área consiga explicar melhor. Eu sei utilizar a programação somente no GLPK, uma referência boa é: H.P. Williams, "Model Building in Mathematical Programming.

Comment: É um problema que somente quem possui todos os dados e variáveis do problema consegue analisar. [Um exemplo](https://www.exceltactics.com/using-solver-to-optimize-solutions-to-costing-problems-in-excel/#Laying-Out-the-Problem) de como utilizar.

Comment: Pessoal, infelizmente até o momento não consegui resolver o problema de forma definitiva e eficiente.
O uso do 'Solver' é uma proposta que demanda tempo de processamento e, quando se trata de um conjunto grande de itens (muitas linhas, no meu caso +600mil), fica impraticável.

Em qualquer momento que surgir soluções ou modificações para o código acima, ou até mesmo uma nova implementação, fico agradecida se compartilharem.
Obrigada.